# Score not working

Tags: android, textview, addition

**Here's my codes**

```js
    //declare a boolean variable for score
    private int optionTxtView = 0  ;
    
    //Search word 
//display score
    public void viewWord(View view)
    {
        score = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourScore);
     tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        tv3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv3);
        searchWord = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.searchWord);
        wordList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.wordList);
        text = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.textHere);
        wordList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.wordList);
        
        
     String s1= search.getText().toString();
        String s2= dbHelper.getData(s1);
      
        if(optionTxtView == 0){
        //display the score on textview1
      tv2.setText(s2);
      optionTxtView = 1;
      
      }
        else{
        //display the score on textview2    
            tv3.setText(s2);
      optionTxtView = 0;
      
        }
        
        calculate();
      
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new ArrayList<String>());
        wordList.setAdapter(adapter);    
     adapter.add(text.getText().toString());
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     text.setText(null);
     
    }
 
    
    private void calculate(){
        x = Integer.parseInt(tv2.getText().toString());
        y = Integer.parseInt(tv3.getText().toString());
     z = x + y;
     score.setText(Integer.toString(z));
    }
```

So basically i decided to have 3 textviews, score, tv2 and tv3. So the first score for the first word should be in the tv2 and the second score should be in tv3. and the sum of this two textviews should be in score.
After putting text on the textview, it will search for the word from the textview in the database by hitting imagebutton. If the word is in the database, it will automatically put the word in the listview and at the same time it SHOULD display the score on two textviews.

I really need help on this. I tried everything i can but it never adds EXCEPT when the value/number in the textview tv2 and tv3 is set from the properties. But whenever the numbers/value is from the database (because that's what it should be) it NEVER ADDS !

Any help will be highly appreciated. Please help me with my codes.

**onCreate Method**

```js
//TAKE NOTE: 16 IMAGEBUTTONS

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        dbHelper =new DBAdapter(this);
        search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textHere);
        words = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edWord);
        scores = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edScore);
        show_addWord = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.show_addWord);
                
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new ArrayList<String>());
        wordList.setAdapter(adapter);
        
        score = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourScore);
     tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        tv3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv3);
        wordList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.wordList);
        text = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.textHere);
        wordList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.wordList);
        blizzard = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.blizzard);
        bomb = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bomb);
        searchWord = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.searchWord);
        wordList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.wordList); //this is til 16
        image1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button1);
  image16 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button16);

  timer = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.timer);
  timer.setText("00:00:30");
  countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(30000,1000);
  
  final AutoCompleteTextView text = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.textHere);
  
  final ImageButton image1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button1); //this is til 16
  final ImageButton image16 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button16);  
  
   
  final int[] myPics = { R.drawable.a, R.drawable.b, R.drawable.c,
    R.drawable.e }; //this is til z
  
  //this is til 16
  int rando = (int)(Math.random()* 5);
  image1.setImageResource(myPics[rando]);
  image1.setId(myPics[rando]);
  

//this is from a -z  
  OnClickListener myCommoClickListner = new OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Log.i(TAG,"arg0.getId() = " + arg0.getId());
                
                if(arg0.getId()==R.drawable.a){
                    Log.i(TAG,"arg0.getId()="+arg0.getId());
                    generatedString=generatedString+"a"; //[PLACEE RESPACTIVE CHARACTEER HERE]
                    text.setText(generatedString);
                    ((ImageButton) arg0).setImageResource(R.drawable.changea);
                    
                     
            if (!timeHasStarted) {
                countDownTimer.start();
                timeHasStarted = true;
                }
                                        else{
                                         if(arg0.getId()==R.drawable.z){
                                                                              Log.i(TAG,"arg0.getId() = " + arg0.getId());
                                                                              generatedString = generatedString+"z";
                                                                              text.setText(generatedString);
                                                                              ((ImageButton) arg0).setImageResource(R.drawable.changez);
                                                                              
                                                                              if (!timeHasStarted) {
                                                                   countDownTimer.start();
                                                                   timeHasStarted = true;
                                                                   }
                                                                    }
   }
   
  };

  
  image1.setOnClickListener(myCommoClickListner);
  image2.setOnClickListener(myCommoClickListner);
  image3.setOnClickListener(myCommoClickListner);
  image4.setOnClickListener(myCommoClickListner);
  image5.setOnClickListener(myCommoClickListner);
  image6.setOnClickListener(myCommoClickListner);
  image7.setOnClickListener(myCommoClickListner);
  image8.setOnClickListener(myCommoClickListner);
  image9.setOnClickListener(myCommoClickListner);
  image10.setOnClickListener(myCommoClickListner);
  image11.setOnClickListener(myCommoClickListner);
  image12.setOnClickListener(myCommoClickListner);
  image13.setOnClickListener(myCommoClickListner);
  image14.setOnClickListener(myCommoClickListner);
  image15.setOnClickListener(myCommoClickListner);
  image16.setOnClickListener(myCommoClickListner);
        
    }
```

LOGCAT
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it never adds EXCEPT when the value/number in the textview tv2 and tv3
>   is set from the properties

You will need to put your code in the `onClick` button or anything that **listen** to the user's action. After that, you can get your `textview's` value and do something with it.

From the look of your code, i suggest you to **move** all of the **initializations** in the `onCreate`:

```
        //move this code to onCreate
        score = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourScore);
        tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        tv3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv3);
        searchWord = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.searchWord);
        wordList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.wordList);
        text = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.textHere);
        wordList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.wordList);

    //also move this
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new ArrayList<String>());
    wordList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

After that, call your `viewWord()` in the `onClick` (or anything you like), example :

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        viewWord(v); //v is your button
    }
 });
```

**UPDATE**

After looking the **exception** in your `logcat`, it seems the error occurred because the integer has some `whitespaces` : "2 " <- a space after 2

Try :

```
 x = Integer.parseInt(tv2.getText().toString().replaceAll("\\s",""));
y = Integer.parseInt(tv3.getText().toString().replaceAll("\\s",""));
```

The idea is to **remove** all of the **whitespaces** before parse it to `Integer`.

Feel free to comment if you have some questions or if i miss understood you :)

Comment: viewWord is called in my xml
in my imagebutton there i declare it like this : onClick = "viewWord"

@BlazeTama

Comment: Suggestions are highly appreciated :) I am new in android programming so I ask people who have broader knowledge on this matter than me. I appreciate your help. It's just that I can't figure out why its not working. I'm sorry if it confused you. 
So, the search, adding an item in listview and displaying score in the textviews is done in viewWord. the first two is perfectly working but when its in calculate() method, my app closes. I don't know why. I have the logcat here. I'll post it so that you'll easily know.

Comment: @BlazeTama I already updated the question :) Included the logcat snip

Comment: @LabLey the log cat said the problem is in your onClick method. (look at the "caused by"). Please post your onClick code

Comment: @LabLey i see. Please see my updated code and post your complete logcat (below "caused by"), if possible double click the log cat and tell me which line is creating the error.

Comment: it gives another error. in
adapter.add(text.getText().toString());
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

when i transfer 
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new ArrayList<String>());
        wordList.setAdapter(adapter);   
in onCreate :(

Comment: @LabLey please post your new, complete onCreate method.

Comment: @LabLey move ALL findViewById's to the TOP of your onCreate, just BELOW setContentView. You get an error because "wordList" ins not yet initialized (findViewById), so its still null but you set an adapter for it.

Comment: I checked my adapter and i saw this one. I didn't think that this affect or the one making this problem but, is my adapter correct? 
I just feel confused. i dunno why. this
 private static final String SCORE ="score";
in my 
private static final String DATABASE_NAME= "BoogleIt";
 private static final String TABLE_NAME ="dbtable";
 private static final String UID ="_id";
 private static final String WORD ="word";
 private static final String SCORE ="score";
 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=4;
 private Context context;

Comment: I am still getting the errors on adapter.add(text.getText().toString());
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
which is :: adapter cannot be resolved

Comment: @LabLey leave the database for now, better we focus on your question first. Try to make your adapter global (move ArrayAdapter<String> adapter outside onCreate) so it can accessed globally

Comment: @LabLey I see you dont really understand what you are doing (im not blaming you), we just fix your question here and you can create another question about the database. Its not because i dont want to help you, but SO works this way : 1 question, 1 answer

Comment: I understand that @BlazeTama . I'm a newbie and most of my codes are based on the tutorials/answers given and as It works, I also start to understand the codes. About the previous suggestion, the result is that, it doesnt load now .. :(

Comment: Logcat: Caused By: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System Services not available to Activities before OnCreate() @BlazeTama

Comment: its still not adding @BlazeTama